# MPC508AP as central IC on audio input selector board

Tags: audio, preamp

I am working on audio preamp and for the input selector I've created following design:
[image]
[image]
Now, as you can see, I've chosen [Texas Instrument's MPC508AP Analog Multiplexer](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/mpc509.pdf) for input switching IC. However, in its datasheet, I could not find channel crosstalk and other audio related operating parameters and I wanted to know, if this IC is even suitable for audio applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be very aware of the injection of trash on the control pins (+-0.5volt of MCU clocking trash) that rides the OFF and rides the ON control levels.

Expect 100MHz ringing (that is approximately how fast the VDD rings on modern MCUs, as the leadframe inductance resonates with the onchip junction/poly capacitors) to be everywhere, including all pins of your analog multiplexer.

Cure? 10Kohm and 1uF SMT cap as LowPassFilter in each control wire, the 1uF shunting that 100Mhz trash to some GND *other* than the Audio ground.

Answer (score 1):

> However, in its datasheet, I could not find channel crosstalk and
>   other audio related operating parameters and I wanted to know, if this
>   IC is even suitable for audio applications?

Page 4 and page 6: -

[image]

So that's the crosstalk but regards "other audio related operating parameters" I think you need to be much more specific. Graphs of performance cover up to 10 kHz and that implies it is for an audio applicattion but, I suspect nobody would call it top-range hiFi.

Comment: @KernelPanic you asked specifically about crosstalk and I found where the crosstalk detail is given in the data sheet. You also asked if this chip were suitable for audio applications. I answered both yet you award the other answer (that doesn't answer these) the bonus points - can you state why?